# Trying to play audio files on arduino via Usb Host Shield

Tags: arduino-mega, usb, audio, teensy

I want to build a program that will seek audio file inside a USB DOK (DisK On Key/Pen Drive) when it is inserted to the Circuits@Home USB Host shield. After a specified file will be found i want it to be played via the Audio library and the Teensy 3.1 12 Bit Analog Output.

Alternatively, I can use an Arduino MEGA with the shield and the TMRpcm library: https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki

I've saw that there's a sample with SD card and I've fiddled a lot to get the USB Host Shield 2.0 library to work and succeeded. However I've found a simpler implementation of it in the UsbFat library: https://github.com/greiman/UsbFat

Now basically I need to connect between these two libraries but sadly I've failed to understand how to convert "play_sd_wav.h" to use the UsbFat Library.

Or, more simply put, how do I command a USB pen drive like it is a SD card and pull an audio file from it?

Anyone can help please?

Thank You,

Ziv